# Spiders stop crawling after first request

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got an issue in my code. After sending first request the spiders stop crawling and not visit other sites. Without callback method I got a list with all sites I want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class CrawlingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myfancycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["domiporta.pl"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.domiporta.pl/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"mieszkanie/wynajme/*[a-z]*(\?PageNumber=[0-9]*)*$")), callback="parse_html"),
    )

    def parse_html(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        datas = soup.findAll("article")
        for data in datas:
            clean_data = self.clean_data(data)

            # print(data)
            # yield {
            #   "price": clean_data[0],
            #   "price_for_m": clean_data[3],
            #   "area": clean_data[1],
            #   "rooms_amount": clean_data[2],
            #   "title": clean_data[4],
            #   "offer": "for rent" if "wynajem" in clean_data[10] or "wynajem" in clean_data[4] else "for sale",
            #   "short_description": clean_data[10],
            # }

    def clean_data(self, data):
        return [el.strip().replace("\xa0", " ") for el in data.text.split("\n") if
                el.strip().replace("\xa0", " ") != "" and el not in (
                'WYRÓŻNIONE', 'OBEJRZANE', 'Więcej', 'Skontaktuj się')]
```

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong?

Greeings!

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch requests for each of the links contained in the article elements that you are scraping back to the scrapy engine.

I also advise not using Beautiful soup and instead using the built in scrapy parsing functionality.  It is much faster than using bs4

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule



class CrawlingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myfancycrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["domiporta.pl"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.domiporta.pl/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"mieszkanie/wynajme/*[a-z]*(\?PageNumber=[0-9]*)*$")), callback="parse_html"),
    )

    def parse_html(self, response):
        fields = ["price","price_for_m","area","rooms_amount","title","offer","short_description"]
        for article in response.xpath("//article"):
            data = [el.strip().replace("\xa0", " ")
                    for el in article.xpath(".//text()").getall()
                    if el.strip().replace("\xa0", " ")
                    and el not in ('WYRÓŻNIONE', 'OBEJRZANE', 'Więcej', 'Skontaktuj się')]
            offer = "for rent" if "wynajem" in data[10] or "wynajem" in data[4] else "for sale"
            yield dict(zip(fields, [data[0], data[3], data[1], data[4], offer, data[10]]))
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article.xpath(".//a/@href").get()))
```

Comment: I will check it, in the way I finally implemented it, it takes about 10-15mins. I'd be glad if it's possible to do it faster. With those links, there were the problem with Rule parameters, because callback automaticly changer "follow" parameter to False. Changing it to True works perfectly. Thank you for support!